# Molasses - “Full Flavor” vs “Mild Flavor”

Tags: flavor

What is the difference between *Full Flavor* and *Mild Flavor* of [molasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molasses)?

Is it produced differently? Contents differ? Is the mild a diluted form of the other?

When to use which one in what kind of recipes?

The examples shown here in this photo are both [unsulphured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molasses#Unsulphured_molasses).

[image: Photo of two bottles of Molasses, both of brand name “Brer Rabbit”, one marked “Full Flavor” and the other marked “Mild Flavor”]

Comment: As a note, some brands also offer an even stronger "Blackstrap".

Comment: If you are tempted to try blackstrap, I highly recommend finding a bottle you can sample somewhere before investing in it. It's a very different taste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight from the Rabbit's website: http://www.brerrabbit.com/questions/#7

> Q: What are there the different grades of Brer Rabbit molasses?
>
> A: Brer Rabbit molasses comes in three grades: Mild Flavor, Full
> Flavor and Blackstrap.
>
> - • Mild Flavor: Lightest color and is the sweetest, is used to sweeten hot cereals, yogurts, or hot drinks, like coffee, tea or hot
>   cocoa
> - • Full Flavor: More concentrated and has a richer flavor than Mild, that is used in gingerbreads, cookies, pies, cakes, and glazes
> - • Blackstrap: Bold, robust flavor used in slow-cooked dishes, like such as baked beans or barbeque sauces. Blackstrap is also an
>   excellent source of Calcium and Magnesium and a good source of
>   Potassium.

I'd guess that the difference is the same thing, different words, as Crosby's "cooking" and "fancy" The fancy or mild is boiled down cane juice (without the sugar removed) and has more sugar and a more carmel-ish taste.

> The highest grade of molasses available, [fancy molasses](http://www.crosbys.com/wp-content/themes/crosbys/pdf/Fancy_Molasses_Retail.pdf) is the pure juice of the sugar cane, condensed, inverted and purified. It is 100% natural and contains no additives or preservatives. It is a bit lighter in colour than the other molasses products, and the flavour is tangy sweet.
>
> [Blackstrap molasses](http://www.crosbys.com/wp-content/themes/crosbys/pdf/Blackstrap_Molasses_Retail.pdf) is the highly-concentrated, final by-product of the refined sugar manufacturing process. As the sugar crystallizes, the residual cane juice thickens into a dark mass and is separated out through a centrifuge. The resulting molasses is very dark with a robust, somewhat bitter flavour. Like the fancy molasses, it is a pure product and contains no added sulphates or sulphites.
>
> [Cooking molasses](http://www.crosbys.com/wp-content/themes/crosbys/pdf/Cooking_Molasses_Retail.pdf) is a blend of blackstrap and fancy molasses. It is thicker and darker than fancy molasses — less sweet, with a more “full-flavoured” taste.

http://www.crosbys.com/products/molasses-products/#!products